# Ksql tumbling window count sink to postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I have created few tumbling window tables to count number of messages per hour/per day.I are trying to sink that in postgres database table. But when I am trying to sink it gives primary key violation instead of it updating the existing records.
Is there any way we can sink these counts in db table?
below is ksql table query and sink connector configuration

```
CREATE TABLE daily_msg_count_tbl WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='daily_msg_count_all', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=3,VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS 
SELECT
  'X' X,COUNT(*) as DAILY_MSG_COUNT_ALL,timestamptostring(windowstart, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as report_time
FROM data-stream 
WINDOW TUMBLING ( SIZE 24 HOURS )
GROUP BY 'X'
EMIT CHANGES;
```

Sink connector configuration :-

```
{"name":"daily_msg_count_all_sink",
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
 "connection.url":"db url",
"connection.user":"",
"connection.password":"", 
"topics":"daily_msg_count_all",
"auto.evolve":"true",
"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"auto.create":"true",
"insert_mode":"upsert",
"value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url":"schema url",
"pk.mode":"record_value",
"pk.fields":"REPORT_TIME,WINDOWSTART"}}
```

what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Please share example records from daily_msg_count_all topic and your table schema

Comment: @OneCricketeer :- please find below sample data and table schema 
```[{'daily_count': 859, 'report_time': '2022-11-02 00:00:00'}, {'daily_count': 1013, 'report_time': '2022-11-03 00:00:00'}] ```
table schema is as follows :-
```CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS daily_msg_count_all(id serial4 not null,daily_count bigint,report_time_start TIMESTAMP not null unique);```
so every time if any new message comes in topic it should upsert if date time already in database else do insert.